# Expand specific headings in Word VBA - O365 ProPlus

Tags: text, ms-word, find

I have checkboxes for different answers to questions in a document. Based on what is checked, I want to expand a more detailed section of questions for the user. I have the If statement for the checkboxes correct, but I can't figure out how to expand specific headings later in my document either by text or section number.

I have tried this loop to find the specific text in the heading and expand it

```
If ccCheckBox.Checked Then
Do Until Selection.Find.Found = False
    If Selection.Text Like "Licensing Discovery Questions" Then
    Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1")
    Selection.Find.Execute
        Else: Selection.Paragraphs(1).CollapsedState = False
    Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1")
    Selection.Find.Execute
    End If 
Loop
End if
```

I have added continuous sections between each heading in my document and tried this code to unhide the follow up questions

```
If ccCheckBox.Checked Then
doc.Sections(2).Range.Font.Hidden = False
End if
```

I have tried assigning the text I'm looking for to a string and expanding the string, but did not work that out either.

I am running Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus

Comment: Could you please be more specific about *how* the code shown in the question "doesn't work" and how to identify a heading? The information provided is so vague it's difficult to provide an exact answer. Also, please check the code formatting in the question - you can use the [edit] link to correct it.

Comment: Both codes execute without error but nothing happens. First code, everything stays collapsed and second code everything stays hidden.

Comment: I recommend you use F8 to "step through" the code and look after each line where the Selection is. It's possible `Find` is looking in the first "found" selection for the second search term (looking whether Heading 1 is in Licensing Discovery Questions). Also, don't use `Else : ` - put everything for `Else` in its own line so that the code is clear to read. It's not clear what you expect this code to be doing, as far as the `Find` part goes. Without knowing that it's not possible to figure out why `CollapseState` isn't doing what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution by switching to Active X Check Boxes and using the following code for each check box.

```
Private Sub CheckBoxNameHere_Click()

If CheckBoxNameHere.Value = True Then
ActiveDocument.Sections(2).Range.Font.Hidden = False
Else: ActiveDocument.Sections(2).Range.Font.Hidden = True
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Your use of ActiveX checkboxes has nothing in particular to do with your 'solution'; the same can be done just as easily with content control & userform checkboxes. Your 'solution' also has nothing to do with expanding/collapsing headings; instead you're using the less reliable approach of hiding content - which only works if the user has Word configured to not show hidden text. But, then, expanding/collapsing only works on more recent Word versions. Finally, if your document needs to be useable on a Mac, you need to know ActiveX controls are not supported there.